# Trouble with a query subselect

Tags: mysql, subquery, errors

I am trying to merge 2 large queries together and can't get it to work. I have an almost working query, except I can't get the server to accept the `p.products_id` in the nested query. Can anyone help work around this?

The strange inner select with many `UNION ALL` generates a list of all dates in a range. (adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range).

The number of levels of nesting seems excessive, but it's the only way I could get the query to work at all.

```
select p.products_id, 
       ( SELECT count(*) 
         from ( select ( SELECT if(v1.quantity, v1.quantity, null) 
                         FROM inventory_history v1 
                         where v1.products_id = p.products_id 
                           AND v1.inventory_date <= t1.date 
                         ORDER BY v1.inventory_date desc limit 1 
                        ) as quantity 
                FROM ( SELECT a.date
                       FROM ( SELECT curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY AS date
                              FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
                              CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
                              CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
                             ) a
                       WHERE a.date >= curdate() - INTERVAL 400 DAY
                      ) t1
                having quantity is not null
               ) x
        ) as count 
from products p 
where p.master_categories_id=264;
```

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'p.products_id' in 'where clause'

What I'm trying to do: *inventory_history* contains snapshots of inventory levels by date. The data is stored sparsely -- only adds a record when inventory changes. Most of the query is converting that sparse data into results for all dates in range, then I want to count the number of days where the inventory quantity is > 0.

Server version: 10.1.35-MariaDB FreeBSD Ports

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e199d540f40e4362e6aa1d667e17fcac

Answer (score 1):

There might be a way to rearrange parts of the correlated subquery so that it can reference the outer level's `products_id` directly, rather than in a subquery/derived table of its own, but in the end I had too little patience to find it.

Instead, I can offer you a different approach to calculating the same results, which uses variables:

```
SELECT
  p.products_id
, (
    SELECT
      SUM(
        DATEDIFF(to_date, GREATEST(from_date, CURDATE() - INTERVAL 400 DAY)) * factor
      )
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          IF(h.products_id = @p, @d, CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS to_date
        , @d := h.inventory_date                                 AS from_date
        , (quantity > 0)                                         AS factor
        , @p := h.products_id                                    AS products_id
        FROM
          inventory_history AS h
        ORDER BY
          h.products_id ASC
        , h.inventory_date DESC
      ) AS v1
    WHERE
      v1.products_id = p.products_id
      AND v1.to_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 400 DAY
  ) AS count
FROM
  (SELECT @p := null, @d := null) AS init
, products AS p
WHERE
  p.master_categories_id=264
;
```

With the help of two variables – `@p` to keep track of the current `products_id`, and `@d` to carry over `inventory_date` to the preceding record of the same product – the `v1` derived table turns `inventory_history` into a set of date ranges, with a flag (`factor`) to indicate whether the range qualifies for the `count` result or not.

The derived table's definition is two levels deep, so it cannot reference the main query's `products_id`.  It simply returns the entire set.  However, the `SELECT` that is using `v1` is where `p.products_id` is valid, and that is where filtering on `products_id` happens.

The count itself is then simply a matter of adding up the date ranges' lengths, using the `DATEDIFF(end_date, start_date)` function.  The starting day expression (`GREATEST(...)`) simply makes sure that the earliest date range's starting point, for the purposes of the query, is no earlier than 400 days from now.

Here is a link to a live demo of this solution at dbfiddle.uk using your test setup:

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=dc5baefec8902a99bf807115aaa235ba